# Preroll an SKVideoNode w/AVPlayer before scene transition?

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, skvideonode

I am using an `AVPlayer` with an `SKVideoNode` attached to a scene.  That is the only node for that `SKScene`.  I am playing out that video intermingled with a set of other scenes loaded with a variety of `SKSpriteNode` nodes.

I want to pre-roll the `AVPlayer` so that the video has begun playing just before (or as) it becomes visible during an `SKScene` transition.  And yet I can't seem to do so without getting an intervening black flash.

Just as the scene containing the video disappears, I reset it (I stuff the AVPlayer object into the `SKVideoNode`'s user dictionary).  This appears to work:

```
SKVideoNode *v = ...;
AVPlayer *player = [[v userData] objectForKey:@"AVPlayer"];
if ([player isKindOfClass:[AVPlayer class]]) {
    [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

When the scene is about to appear that contains the video, I do this:

```
SKTransition *trans = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:1.0];
[self.skView presentScene:theScene transition:trans];
[self performSelector:@selector(startVideoInScene:)
           withObject:theScene
           afterDelay:0.2];
```

then...

```
- (BOOL)startVideoInScene:(SKScene *)theScene
{
    for (SKNode *n in [theScene children])
        if ([n isKindOfClass:[SKVideoNode class]]) {
            SKVideoNode *v = (SKVideoNode *)n;
            AVPlayer *player = [[v userData] objectForKey:@"AVPlayer"];
            if ([player isKindOfClass:[AVPlayer class]]) {
                [v play];
                return YES;
            }
        }
    return NO;
}
```

This does not work without starting with short duration of black before the video.

Anyone had success with this?

I have a haunting suspicion that all content on a `SKScene` is suspended during its transition, and there's no way around it. Well, apart from transitioning out all nodes of the current scene, keeping that current scene, and transitioning a new `SKVideoNode` onto it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616190/playing-back-video-in-an-skvideonode-causes-a-black-flash-before-playback-begins) suggests making a still image from the first frame of the video, and making that an `SKSpriteNode` that is to be used as the image that first appears as the scene transitions. Then, when the transition is over, hide that poster image (the `SKSpriteNode`) and play your video.

Now, what i'm doing in a project i have going right now, is actually using the black to my advantage. The context of the game allows me to do this, but i basically let my scene transition to black, the start of the video (in my case an mp4) has its black start, then fades in from black as the video plays.